# Can't install tailwind css in my Angular project

Tags: angular, webpack, tailwind-css

First of all, I was following this guide (and so others): https://medium.com/@jacobneterer/angular-and-tailwindcss-2388fb6e0bab

I have been trying to install tailwind in my angular project with no success. Besides this, I have even created an angular project from 0 to try to do a basic installation and I have not been able to either.

I have made all the configurations that appear in this quick guide, including changing the application builder for the custom webpack builder and the angular.json configuration.

Current error on ng serve:
[image]

Dependencies on package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-scss": "^2.1.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.8.10",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it downgrading the *postcss-loader*. It seems that it is not working with the 4.0 version and I had to put manually the 3.0:

```
npm uninstall postcss-loader --save-dev
npm install postcss-loader@~3.0.0 --save-dev
```

I hope it has helped you. Some configurations in the angular and tailwind environment may still fail, if anyone needs help with any other configuration feel free to contact me about it

Answer (score 0):

I have too few points to either upvote the above comment or answer in addition, so I'm here to say that jgascona's response did indeed solve it for me as well. Thank you!